# SignalR: Web-socket Handshake issue with Error 400 with Nginx

Tags: websocket, signalr, devops, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

I have an asp.net mvc 5 application i have implemented SignalR with web sockets using postgresql. all functionality working fine when i move my application to staging server and enable web sockets we have implemented nginx for load balancing every time signalr throw error for `web socket secure (wss)` connection "Handshake Error with 400 Code."

Config i have use right now:

```
upstream servername_websocket {
  server abc:8000;
}

server {
  listen 8000 ssl;
  server_name ~\.servername\.com$;
  ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/servername.com.chained.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/servername.com.key;

  location / {
     proxy_pass http://servername_websocket;
     proxy_http_version 1.1;
     proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
     proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
  }
}
```

Thanks